# Python: How to replace tqdm progress bar by next one in nested loop?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) module in Jupyter Notebook. And let's say I have the following piece of code with a nested for loop.

```
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(3)):
    for j in tqdm(range(5)):
        time.sleep(1)
```

The output looks like this:

```
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:15<00:00, 5.07s/it]
100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:10<00:00, 2.02s/it]

100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:05<00:00, 1.01s/it]

100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:05<00:00, 1.01s/it]
```

Is there any option, how to show only **current** `j` progress bar during the run? So, the final output after finishing the iteration would look like this?

```
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:15<00:00, 5.07s/it]
100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:05<00:00, 1.01s/it]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use leave param when create progress bar. Something like this:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(3)):
    for j in tqdm(range(5), leave=bool(i == 2)):
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This will delete the inner progress bar and re-create it every time. So, if there is more work being done in these loops instead of just sleep, the progress bar will play hide and seek.

Comment: solution has disadvantages, but I think it is better way to implement what author needs. less code less errors)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly, what I was looking for!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help with `progress_apply` methods for pandas objects.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by resetting the progress bar object every time before inner loop starts.

Try the following code to achieve the results you want.

```
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

#initializing progress bar objects
outer_loop=tqdm(range(3))
inner_loop=tqdm(range(5))

for i in range(len(outer_loop)):
    inner_loop.refresh()  #force print final state
    inner_loop.reset()  #reuse bar
    outer_loop.update() #update outer tqdm

    for j in range(len(inner_loop)):
        inner_loop.update() #update inner tqdm
        time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi @hamza-khurshid Thanks for your answer. I have added some more to is it is below. Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @michael-schroter for bringing this to my attention and @jaroslav-bezděk for the original post.

I'd prefer @anton-pomieshchenko's answer. However as noted, the inner bar keeps disappearing and re-appearing each time the outer bar updates, which could look bad if it happens quickly and frequently.

Correct answer (assuming you don't need to re-use the outer bar, but do want to re-use the inner one):

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

with tqdm(range(3)) as outer:
    inner_total = 3
    with tqdm(total=inner_total) as inner:
        for i in outer:
            inner.reset(inner_total)  # reinitialise without clearing
            for j in range(inner_total):
                sleep(1)
                inner.update()
            inner.refresh()  # print last state without clearing
```

Comment: This solution works as I expect both progress bars to behave: they stick to the top. Works fine with logging, too. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Please find the modified answer from @hamza-khurshid for three loops.

```py
import time
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

#initializing progress bar objects
outer_loop=tqdm(range(3))
mid_loop=tqdm(range(5))
inner_loop=tqdm(range(7))


for i in range(len(outer_loop)):

    mid_loop.refresh()  #force print final state
    mid_loop.reset()  #reuse bar
    outer_loop.update() #update outer tqdm

    for j in range(len(mid_loop)):
        inner_loop.refresh()  #force print final state
        inner_loop.reset()  #reuse bar
        mid_loop.update()  ##update mid tqdm

        for k in range(len(inner_loop)):
            inner_loop.update() #update inner tqdm
            time.sleep(1)
print(i,j,k)
```

Please find the output below:

[image]

This is also the [answer](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/923#issuecomment-607313907) for the question on [github](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/923#issuecomment-607313907)

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael